# How to test a bitmap retrieved from non-empty cache?

Tags: java, android, caching, bitmap

I write the bitmap into the cacheing like this

```
 File cacheDir = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();
                        File f = new File(cacheDir, data);
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                                    f);
                            bm2.compress(
                                    Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
                                    100, out);
                            out.flush();
                            out.close();

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

and take it like this

```
File cacheDirz = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();
                File fa = new File(cacheDirz, data);

                FileInputStream fis = null;
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(fa);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
```

But is there a way to check out the retrieved bitmap that exists? It is not null but it has nothing.

Thank !

Comment: Even if there is a catch you call decodeStream(). Not correct.

Comment: You are not using `fa.exists()`.

Comment: I used fa.exists but it does not work

Comment: What do you mean ? Unclear if the file exists. And still your code calls decodeStream if there is a catch. "it does not work" is a useless error description. Come to the point!